# Inverting slider scale on pie chart

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create this pie chart where by changing the slider, the slice increases or decreases and then the "Perda na carteira" section will increase or decrease, respectively.

Basically, when all sliders are on "Perda potencial 100%", the "Perda na carteira" should also be at 100%. I've tried using  `direction: rtl`, but this simply changes the slider to go from right to left and doesn't actually change the values.

Thank you in advance!

```js
    /************** Canvas ***************/
    let myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    myCanvas.width = 300;
    myCanvas.height = 300;

    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d"),
        val;


    /************** Slider Variables ***************/
    //Gruen 
    var sliderGruen = document.getElementById("gruen");
    var outputGruen = document.getElementById("gruenValue");
    outputGruen.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderGruen.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    sliderGruen.oninput = function () {
        outputGruen.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
    };

    //Gelb  
    var sliderGelb = document.getElementById("gelb");
    var outputGelb = document.getElementById("gelbValue");
    outputGelb.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderGelb.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    sliderGelb.oninput = function () {
        outputGelb.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
    };

    //Rot   
    var sliderRot = document.getElementById("rot");
    var outputRot = document.getElementById("rotValue");
    outputRot.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderRot.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    sliderRot.oninput = function () {
        outputRot.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
    };

    //Magenta 
    var sliderMagenta = document.getElementById("magenta");
    var outputMagenta = document.getElementById("magentaValue");
    outputMagenta.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderMagenta.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    sliderMagenta.oninput = function () {
        outputMagenta.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
    };

    //Blau  
    var sliderBlau = document.getElementById("blau");
    var outputBlau = document.getElementById("blauValue");
    outputBlau.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderBlau.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    sliderBlau.oninput = function () {
        outputBlau.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
    };



    /************** Utility Functions ***************/
    function changeColoursData() {
        var colours = {
            "Gruen": parseInt(sliderGruen.value),
            "Gelb": parseInt(sliderGelb.value),
            "Red": parseInt(sliderRot.value),
            "Magenta": parseInt(sliderMagenta.value),
            "Blau": parseInt(sliderBlau.value),
            "Cyan": parseInt(100 - (parseInt(sliderGruen.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderGelb.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderRot.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderMagenta.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderBlau.value) / 5))
        };
        var outputCyan = document.getElementById("cyanValue");
        outputCyan.innerHTML = colours.Cyan + " " + "%";
        return colours;

    }


    function drawPieSlice(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, color) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    /************** Piechart Object ***************/
    var Piechart = function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.canvas = options.canvas;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.colors = options.colors;

        this.draw = function () {
            var total_value = 0;
            var color_index = 0;
            for (var categ in this.options.data) {
                val = this.options.data[categ];
                total_value += val;
            }

            var start_angle = 0;
            for (categ in this.options.data) {
                val = this.options.data[categ];
                var slice_angle = 2 * Math.PI * val / total_value;

                drawPieSlice(
                    this.ctx,
                    this.canvas.width / 2,
                    this.canvas.height / 2,
                    Math.min(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2),
                    start_angle,
                    start_angle + slice_angle,
                    this.colors[color_index % this.colors.length]
                );

                start_angle += slice_angle;
                color_index++;
            }
        };

    };


    /************** Initialize code and draw pie chart ***************/
    function refreshPiechart() {
        var myPiechart = new Piechart(
            {
                canvas: myCanvas,
                data: changeColoursData(),
                colors: ["#00A878", "#FFEA65", "#86CDC5", "#53131E", "#246EB9", "#FF5964"]
                //colours : gruen, gelb, rot, magenta, blau,cyan
            }
        );

        myPiechart.draw();

    }

    refreshPiechart();
```

```css
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #EDDDD4;
    }


    .content {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .slider1 {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #00A878;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;

    }

    .slider2 {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #FFEA65;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;

    }

    .slider3 {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #86CDC5;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;

    }

    .slider4 {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #53131E;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;

    }

    .slider5 {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #246EB9;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    .slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid black 0.15em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #FAF6EB;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid black 0.15em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #FAF6EB;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider3::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid black 0.15em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #FAF6EB;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider4::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid black 0.15em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #FAF6EB;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider5::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid black 0.15em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #FAF6EB;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #FAF6EB;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul {
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .title {
        float: left;
    }

    h5 {
        float: right;
        width: 31%;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 0px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    h4 {
        float: right;
        width: 60%;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 5px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    canvas {
        margin-right: 10px;
        background: #EDDDD4;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <canvas id="myCanvas">


        </canvas>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <div id="slidecontainer">
                    <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>
                    <h5 class="title">Ativo: TSLA</h5>
                    <h5 id="gruenValue">
                        </h1>
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider1" id="gruen"
                            onChange="refreshPiechart();">
                </div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <div id="slidecontainer">
                    <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

                    <h5 class="title">Ativo: MSFT</h5>
                    <h5 id="gelbValue">
                        </h1>
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider2" id="gelb"
                            onChange="refreshPiechart();">
                </div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <div id="slidecontainer">
                    <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

                    <h5 class="title">Ativo: AAPL</h5>
                    <h5 id="rotValue">
                        </h1>
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider3" id="rot"
                            onChange="refreshPiechart();">
                </div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <div id="slidecontainer">
                    <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

                    <h5 class="title">Ativo: HOOD</h5>
                    <h5 id="magentaValue">
                        </h1>
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider4" id="magenta"
                            onChange="refreshPiechart();">
                </div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <div id="slidecontainer">
                    <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

                    <h5 class="title">Ativo: MRNA</h5>
                    <h5 id="blauValue">
                        </h1>
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider5" id="blau"
                            onChange="refreshPiechart();">
                </div>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <div id="slidecontainer">
                    <h4 class="title">Perda na carteira:</h4>
                    <h5 id="cyanValue">
                        </h1>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want the % value of Perda na carteira to invert or you want a slider with inverted Perda na carteira value

Comment: I'd like to have the % value of perda na carteira inverted (essentially, when all sliders are at "Perda potencial 100%" the "Perda na carteira" should be at 100% and not at 0%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to subtract `colours.Cyan` from 100 and display it.

```js
/************** Canvas ***************/
let myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
myCanvas.width = 300;
myCanvas.height = 300;

var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d"),
  val;


/************** Slider Variables ***************/
//Gruen 
var sliderGruen = document.getElementById("gruen");
var outputGruen = document.getElementById("gruenValue");
outputGruen.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderGruen.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
sliderGruen.oninput = function() {
  outputGruen.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
};

//Gelb  
var sliderGelb = document.getElementById("gelb");
var outputGelb = document.getElementById("gelbValue");
outputGelb.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderGelb.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
sliderGelb.oninput = function() {
  outputGelb.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
};

//Rot   
var sliderRot = document.getElementById("rot");
var outputRot = document.getElementById("rotValue");
outputRot.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderRot.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
sliderRot.oninput = function() {
  outputRot.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
};

//Magenta 
var sliderMagenta = document.getElementById("magenta");
var outputMagenta = document.getElementById("magentaValue");
outputMagenta.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderMagenta.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
sliderMagenta.oninput = function() {
  outputMagenta.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
};

//Blau  
var sliderBlau = document.getElementById("blau");
var outputBlau = document.getElementById("blauValue");
outputBlau.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + sliderBlau.value + "%"; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
sliderBlau.oninput = function() {
  outputBlau.innerHTML = "Perda potencial" + " " + this.value + "%";
};



/************** Utility Functions ***************/
function changeColoursData() {
  var colours = {
    "Gruen": parseInt(sliderGruen.value),
    "Gelb": parseInt(sliderGelb.value),
    "Red": parseInt(sliderRot.value),
    "Magenta": parseInt(sliderMagenta.value),
    "Blau": parseInt(sliderBlau.value),
    "Cyan": parseInt(100 - (parseInt(sliderGruen.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderGelb.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderRot.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderMagenta.value) / 5) - (parseInt(sliderBlau.value) / 5))
  };
  var outputCyan = document.getElementById("cyanValue");
  var invertedOutputCyan = 100 - colours.Cyan;
  outputCyan.innerHTML = invertedOutputCyan + " " + "%";
  return colours;

}


function drawPieSlice(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
  ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

/************** Piechart Object ***************/
var Piechart = function(options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.canvas = options.canvas;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.colors = options.colors;

  this.draw = function() {
    var total_value = 0;
    var color_index = 0;
    for (var categ in this.options.data) {
      val = this.options.data[categ];
      total_value += val;
    }

    var start_angle = 0;
    for (categ in this.options.data) {
      val = this.options.data[categ];
      var slice_angle = 2 * Math.PI * val / total_value;

      drawPieSlice(
        this.ctx,
        this.canvas.width / 2,
        this.canvas.height / 2,
        Math.min(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2),
        start_angle,
        start_angle + slice_angle,
        this.colors[color_index % this.colors.length]
      );

      start_angle += slice_angle;
      color_index++;
    }
  };

};


/************** Initialize code and draw pie chart ***************/
function refreshPiechart() {
  var myPiechart = new Piechart({
    canvas: myCanvas,
    data: changeColoursData(),
    colors: ["#00A878", "#FFEA65", "#86CDC5", "#53131E", "#246EB9", "#FF5964"]
    //colours : gruen, gelb, rot, magenta, blau,cyan
  });

  myPiechart.draw();

}

refreshPiechart();
```

```css
<style>body {
  background-color: #EDDDD4;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider1 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00A878;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFEA65;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider3 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #86CDC5;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider4 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #53131E;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider5 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #246EB9;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid black 0.15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAF6EB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid black 0.15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAF6EB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider3::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid black 0.15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAF6EB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider4::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid black 0.15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAF6EB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider5::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid black 0.15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAF6EB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAF6EB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.title {
  float: left;
}

h5 {
  float: right;
  width: 31%;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h4 {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #EDDDD4;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <canvas id="myCanvas">


        </canvas>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <div id="slidecontainer">
          <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>
          <h5 class="title">Ativo: TSLA</h5>
          <h5 id="gruenValue">
            </h1>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider1" id="gruen" onChange="refreshPiechart();">
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div id="slidecontainer">
          <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

          <h5 class="title">Ativo: MSFT</h5>
          <h5 id="gelbValue">
            </h1>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider2" id="gelb" onChange="refreshPiechart();">
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div id="slidecontainer">
          <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

          <h5 class="title">Ativo: AAPL</h5>
          <h5 id="rotValue">
            </h1>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider3" id="rot" onChange="refreshPiechart();">
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div id="slidecontainer">
          <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

          <h5 class="title">Ativo: HOOD</h5>
          <h5 id="magentaValue">
            </h1>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider4" id="magenta" onChange="refreshPiechart();">
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div id="slidecontainer">
          <h5 class="title">Quota: 20%</h5>

          <h5 class="title">Ativo: MRNA</h5>
          <h5 id="blauValue">
            </h1>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider5" id="blau" onChange="refreshPiechart();">
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div id="slidecontainer">
          <h4 class="title">Perda na carteira:</h4>
          <h5 id="cyanValue">
            </h1>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I tried changing the cyan as well by inverting the value, but I was doing that change on the var colours! Thank you brother!

Comment: @RafaelOliveira I am glad it worked for you, You can even upvote my answer. Regards